# Wait for invocation/method to return a value in javascript signalr

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asynchronous, signalr

I can't figure why my code doesn't wait for the invocation to return a value.
Tried making it into a separate function, still the same error.
It looks like I just can't access **.done** function.

Main Code
JS:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/rouletteHub").build();
function HandleBet(event, color){
    var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value);
    var actualPoints = 0;
    
    connection.invoke("GetPtsFromServer").then(function (pts) {
        actualPoints = parseInt(pts);
    })
    
    console.log(actualPoints);
    if (isNaN(amount)){
        ErrorNotANumber();
        return;
    }
    
    if (amount < 0){
        ErrorNegativeNumber();
        return;
    }
    //console.log(amount);
    //console.log(actualPoints)
    if (amount > actualPoints){
            NotEnoughPoints();
            return;
        }
    if (amount > 0){
            connection.invoke("PlaceBet", color.toString(), amount).then(function () {
                PlacedBetSuccess(GetColor2(color), amount);  
                }, function (err) {
                    PlacedBetError();
                })
        }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

C#:

```
public int? GetPtsFromServer()
        {
            if (Context.User?.Identity != null && !Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return null;

            if (Context.User == null) return null;
            var dcId = Context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "urn:discord:id")?.Value;

            return DataWrapper.HelpForTypes.GetPts(Convert.ToUInt64(dcId));
        }
```

When using **.done** instead of **.then** it throws an error
Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: connection.invoke(...).done is not a function
    at HandleBet (Roulette:420)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Roulette:469)
```

JS:

```
connection.invoke("GetPtsFromServer").done(function (pts) {
        actualPoints = parseInt(pts);
    });
```

Comment: [mcve] -> _"**DO NOT** use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). This helps others more easily read and test your code."_

Comment: `.invoke` returns a `Promise` which has no `.done` method. So why do you want to call `.done()` on it?

Comment: I just want to wait for the response from the server and after that continue code, I tried `.done` because I though that it has this method, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Then you might want to have a look at how `Promise`s work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by making `HandleBet` async and inserting `await` before `connection.invoke`.